# Symfony2 Form Events - Drop down lists

Tags: symfony

In a Symfony2 website I'm trying to make a form with 2 (or 3) dropdown lists with a dependency like Country > Region > City. And that city is a field of the element I'm editing with the form. The idea is to fill the lists depending on selections.

I've followed the tutorial with form events here : http://aulatic.16mb.com/wordpress/2011/08/symfony2-dynamic-forms-an-event-driven-approach/
(which is based on webb-on-the-web .com/?p=5)

The issue I have: it all works but when I use the form to edit the element, the city is selected correctly (from DB) but the Country and Region dropdown lists are prefilled and left on 'select a value'. I don't know if it was supposed to work with the tutorial as it is.

The question : how can I make these lists selected? I'm trying to add a POST_SET_DATA event but I can't find a way to select the value in the form field.

Here's the form class : http://pastebin.com/PpWkHxC3 (note that instead of city it's : Field > Topic and topic is a field of a Lesson which the form edits).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I almost had it. If anybody else ever needs this here's what needs to be added to make this solution work perfectly when editing an existing item :

```
class ItemDetailForm extends AbstractType
{
   ...
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA, function (DataEvent $event) use ($refreshTopic) {
            $data = $event->getData();
            $form = $event->getForm();
            if (null === $data) {
                return;
            }

            $form->get('region')->setData($data->getCity()->getRegion());
        });
}
```

Edit: since symfony 2.1, the POST_SET_DATA event is called before the children are added to the form, causing all the get('region') to raise an exception.
The solution is to create this field in the POST_SET_DATA and not in the buildForm() :

```
        /** @var FormFactory $factory */
        $form->add($factory->createNamed('region', 'entity', null, array(
            'class'=>'AcmeBundle:Region',
            'property_path'=>false,
            'empty_value'=>'Choose a value',
            'required'=>true,
            'label'=>'Region'
        )));
```

Note that you need to add the $factory to the 'use' of the closure handling the event :

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA, function (DataEvent $event) use ($refreshTopic, $factory) {
```

Here is the whole form class:

```
<?php
namespace AAA\CoreBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactory;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Form;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use AAA\CoreBundle\Entity\ClassYear;
use AAA\CoreBundle\Entity\Field;
use AAA\CoreBundle\Entity\Lesson;
use AAA\CoreBundle\Form\LessonContentForm;

class LessonDetailForm extends AbstractType
{
    public $country;
    function __construct($country=null) {
        // Get country for classyear dropdown list
        $this->country = $country;
    }
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $factory = $builder->getFormFactory();

        $builder->add('name', null, array('label'=>'Titre de la leçon'));
        $builder->add('description', 'textarea', array('label'=>'Description (définition conceptuelle) Qu\'est-ce que c\'est ? Et à quoi ça sert ? (importance, utilité)'));
        $builder->add('text', 'textarea', array('label'=>'Leçon', 'required'=>false)); // Can't set 'required' on textareas used by TinyMCE
        $builder->add('reperes', 'textarea', array('label'=>'Repères (détectionel) - Quels sont les éléments qui me permettent de repérer que je dois penser à ce concept ?', 'required'=>false));
        $builder->add('other_topic', null, array(
            'required'  =>  false,
            'mapped'     =>  false
        ));

        $refreshField = function ($form, $classyear) use ($factory) {
            /** @var FormFactory $factory */
            /** @var Form $form */
            $form->add($factory->createNamed('field','entity',null, array(
                'class'         => 'AAA\CoreBundle\Entity\Field',
                'mapped'        => false,
                'label'         => 'Matière',
                'empty_value'   => 'Sélectionne une valeur',
                'empty_data'    => null,
                'required'      => false,
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $repository) use ($classyear) {
                    $qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('field')
                        ->innerJoin('field.classyear', 'classyear');

                    if($classyear instanceof ClassYear) {
                        $qb = $qb->where('field.classyear = :classyear')
                            ->setParameter('classyear', $classyear);
                    } elseif(is_numeric($classyear)) {
                        $qb = $qb->where('classyear.id = :classyear_id')
                            ->setParameter('classyear_id', $classyear);
                    } else {
                        $qb = $qb->where('0 = 1');
                    }

                    return $qb;
                }
            )));
        };
        $refreshTopic = function ($form, $field) use ($factory) {
            /** @var FormFactory $factory */
            /** @var Form $form */
            $form->add($factory->createNamed('topic','entity',null, array(
                'class'         => 'AAA\CoreBundle\Entity\Topic',
                'property'      => 'name',
                'label'         => 'Sujet',
                'empty_value'   => 'Sélectionne une valeur',
                'empty_data'    => null,
                'required'      => false,
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $repository) use ($field) {
                    $qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('topic')
                        ->innerJoin('topic.field', 'field');

                    if($field instanceof Field) {
                        $qb = $qb->where('topic.field = :field')
                            ->setParameter('field', $field);
                    } elseif(is_numeric($field)) {
                        $qb = $qb->where('field.id = :field_id')
                            ->setParameter('field_id', $field);
                    } else {
                        $qb = $qb->where('0 = 1');
                    }

                    return $qb;
                }
            )));
        };

        // Populate ddl to show form
        $country = $this->country;
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) use ($refreshTopic, $refreshField, $factory, $country) {
            /** @var Lesson $data */
            $data = $event->getData();
            $form = $event->getForm();

            // Test if null because this event is called 2 times, only the second time with the actual Lesson object (which has null values in the creation case)
            if($data != null)
                // In case of creation
                if($data->getId()==null) {
                    // Creates empty fields
                    $refreshTopic($form, null);
                    $refreshField($form, null);
                }
                // In case of edition
                else {
                    if ($data->getTopic() != null) {
                        $refreshTopic($form, $data->getTopic()->getField());
                        if ($data->getTopic()->getField() != null) {
                            $refreshField($form, $data->getTopic()->getField()->getClassYear());
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        $refreshField($form, null);
                        $refreshTopic($form, null);
                    }
                }

            /** @var FormFactory $factory */
            $form->add($factory->createNamed('classyear', 'entity', null, array(
                'class'         => 'AAACoreBundle:ClassYear',
                'property'      => 'name'.$country,
                'mapped'        => false,
                'label'         => 'Année',
                'empty_value'   => 'Sélectionne une valeur',
                'empty_data'    => null,
                'required'      => false,
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $repository) {
                    return $repository->createQueryBuilder('classyear')
                        ->orderBy('classyear.sort');
                }
            )));
        });
        // Populate ddl when form was posted
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_BIND, function (FormEvent $event) use ($refreshTopic, $refreshField) {
            $form = $event->getForm();
            $data = $event->getData();

            if(array_key_exists('classyear', $data)) {
                $refreshField($form, $data['classyear']);
            }
            if(array_key_exists('field', $data)) {
                $refreshTopic($form, $data['field']);
            }
        });

        // Select value in ddl when editing
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) use ($refreshTopic) {
            /** @var Lesson $data */
            $data = $event->getData();
            $form = $event->getForm();
            if (null === $data || null === $data->getId() ) {
                return;
            }

            if ($data->getTopic() != null) {
                $form->get('field')->setData($data->getTopic()->getField());
                if ($data->getTopic()->getField() != null) {
                    $form->get('classyear')->setData($data->getTopic()->getField()->getClassYear());
                }
            }
        });
    }
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'LessonDetailForm';
    }
    /** @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AAA\CoreBundle\Entity\Lesson'
        ));
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: I have a question to you Thomas, I have a similar dropdown dependency in my system. My case is that I create the form and I bind it with other values (the request indeed), how can I set the `region` data and keep working both when I create the form and I'm not binding it and when I bind the data with the request?

Comment: Sorry, I really didn't understand that question. :)
(mind that the binding of Forms has been improved in 2.1, so you just call bind() and not bindRequest() anymore.

Comment: Hello thomas. I am struggling like hell to do what you did. Unfortunately the tutorial with form events is not anymore there. The link is dead. Could you be son kind and edit your answer so other like me can move forward. That would be really great:) Thank you in advance. Cheers. Marc

Comment: Hi Thomas, I'm trying to implement something similar, just with school -> grade -> class whilst editing the class. I'd like to select a school and have it show me the available grades under it. Your pastebin link seems dead - do you perhaps have some kind of example of your form class? Would really appreciate it!

Comment: I added the form class to the post. Hope it helps.

Comment: Great stuff, that looks like a mean mother! Thanks so much man!