# "Unable to reverse value for property path" for Symfony2 form ChoiceType field on Select2

Tags: php, ajax, forms, symfony

Long story short, in Symfony 2.8 I've got `Movie` entity with `actors` field, which is `ArrayCollection` of entity `Actor` (`ManyToMany`) and I wanted the field to be ajax-loaded Select2.
When I don't use Ajax, the form is:

```
->add('actors', EntityType::class, array(
        'class' => Actor::class,
        'label' => "Actors of the work",
        'multiple' => true,
        'attr' => array(
          'class' => "select2-select",
         ),
       ))
```

And *it works*.

I tried to put there an empty Select field:

```
->add('actors', ChoiceType::class, array(
    'mapped' => false,
    'multiple' => true,
    'attr'=>array(
        'class' => "select2-ajax",
        'data-entity'=>"actor"
    )
))
```

The Select2 Ajax works, everything in DOM looks the same as in previous example, but on form submit I get errors in the profiler: `This value is not valid.`:

```
Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintViolation
Object(Symfony\Component\Form\Form).children[actors] = [0 => 20, 1 => 21]
Caused by:
Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\TransformationFailedException
Unable to reverse value for property path "actors": Could not find all matching choices for the given values
Caused by:
Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\TransformationFailedException
Could not find all matching choices for the given values
```

The funny part is the data received is the same as they were when it was an `EntityType`: `[0 => 20, 1 => 21]`

I marked field as not mapped, I even changed field name to other than Movie entity's field name. I tried adding empty `choices`, I tried to leave it as `EntityType` but with custom `query_builder`, returning empty collection. Now I'm out of ideas.

How should I do it?

**EDIT** after Raymond's answer:

I added DataTransformer:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use CompanyName\Common\CommonBundle\Entity\Actor;
use Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\TransformationFailedException;

class ActorToNumberTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    private $manager;

    public function __construct(ObjectManager $objectManager)
    {
        $this->manager = $objectManager;
    }

    public function transform($actors)
    {
        if(null === $actors)
            return array();

        $actorIds = array();
        foreach($actors as $actor)
            $actorIds[] = $actor->getId();

        return $actorIds;
    }

    public function reverseTransform($actorIds)
    {
        if($actorIds === null)
            return array();

        foreach($actorIds as $actorId)
        {
            $actor = $this->manager->getRepository('CommonBundle:Actor')->find($actorId);
            if(null === $actor)
                throw new TransformationFailedException(sprintf('An actor with id "%s" does not exist!', $actorId));

            $actors[] = $actor;
        }

        return $actors;
    }
}
```

Added it at the end of the `MovieType buildForm()`:

```
$builder->get('actors')
    ->addModelTransformer(new ActorToNumberTransformer($this->manager));
$builder->get('actors')
    ->addViewTransformer(new ActorToNumberTransformer($this->manager));
```

And added service:

```
common.form.type.work:
    class: CompanyName\Common\CommonBundle\Form\Type\MovieType
    arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
    tags:
        - { name: form.type }
```

Nothing changed. On form submit, `reverseTransform()` gets the proper data, but profiler shows the same error. That's a big mistery for me now...

Comment: have you found a solution for your problem? I'm currently stuck with the same problem

Comment: Hello @rogaa, I've just replied with a solution. I was in the same situation, but this link helped me:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#form-events-submitted-data
It use form events in order to manage ajax related entities.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - the problem does not exist anymore. But I know the documentation and especially this part. Unfortunately I wasn't able to get it running(even the symfony example). Maybe you can setup a working solution on gist for the community? Nevertheless thanks 

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add a DTO (Data Transformer ) to transform the value received from your form and return the appropriate object .
Since you're calling the value from Ajax it doesn't recognized it anymore as a an object but a text value.

Examples :

1. [Symfony2 -Use of DTO](https://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html#harder-example-transforming-an-issue-number-into-an-issue-entity)
2. [Form  with jQuery autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34926586/symfony2-form-events-listener-and-data-transformer-error-cannot-instantiate-inte)

Comment: Thanks. Can you look at my edited question? Maybe you'll find something I missed...?

Answer (score 1):

The correct way isn't Data Transformer but Form Events, look here:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#form-events-submitted-data

In the example you have the field sport (an entity, like your `Movie`) and the field position (another entity, like `actors`).
The trick is to use ajax in order to reload entirely the form and use
`PRE_SET_DATA` and `POST_SUBMIT`.

I'm using Symfony 3.x but I think it's the same with 2.8.x

Comment: Thank You , your answer was my leading point to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

When you add data transformers and nothing seems to change, it sounds like the data never goes through your data transformers. The transformation probably fails before your new data transformers are called. Try to add a few lines to your code:

```
$builder->get('actors')->resetViewTransformers();
$builder->get('actors')->resetModelTransformers();
// and then add your own
```